# How to pass BigInteger from java to Postgres?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.2

I need to pass a BigInteger argument to SQL query. (on Postgres 9.2)
I have this code in my DAO:

```
    public List<PersonInfo> select(String id) {
        BigInteger bigIntId = new BigInteger(id);
        JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        return select
            .query("SELECT * FROM PE.SUPPLIER_INPUT_DATA WHERE ID = ?",
                    new Object[] { bigIntId },
                    new PersonRowMapper());
    }
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
{"error":"Error invoking getPersonInfoById.[org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM PE.SUPPLIER_INPUT_DATA WHERE ID = ?]; 
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.math.BigInteger. 
Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.]"}
```

The id is of type bigint

Tried to pass plain String - also throws type exception.
Googled the message in the exception - no relevant result.
Any ideas?

Comment: ID is of which datatype ?

Comment: The JDBC specification does not include support for `BigInteger`; you either need to use a different datatype (eg BigDecimal with scale 0), or find out if the PostgreSQL driver offers some implementation specific way to set a BigInteger value.

Comment: Try to pass it as [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) maybe that works?

Comment: Try using java.lang.Long instead.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, mind to post your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for `BigInteger` was added in JDBC 4.1 (Java 7), somehow I had missed that when I originally wrote this answer.

Specifically section 3.1 Overview of changes of the JDBC 4.1 specification states:

> - Additional Mappings to Table B-4, Mapping from Java Object to JDBC Types
>     [..]
>     Support was also added to map `java.lang.BigInteger`*[sic]* to JDBC `BIGINT`.
> - Additional Mappings to Table B-5, Performed by `setObject` and `setNull` between Java Object Types and Target JDBC Types
>     [..]
>     Allow conversion of `java.lang.BigInteger`*[sic]* to `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `LONGVARCHAR`, and `BIGINT`.

I'm not sure how well this is supported across drivers.

### Original answer

The JDBC specification does not include support for `BigInteger`; you either need to use a different datatype (eg `BigDecimal` with scale 0), or find out if the PostgreSQL driver offers some implementation specific way to set a `BigInteger` value.

Comment: @valijon You're suggested edit is not appropriate. You're correct that the class is called `java.math.BigInteger`, but this is a literal quote from the JDBC 4.1 specification, which has this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, using Types.BIGINT as a refinement works. I used it in combination with BatchPreparedStatementSetter, this is simple and very readable:

```
 @Transactional
public void saveStuff(List<Foo> foos) {
    int batchSize = foos.size();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO db.foo " +
            "(sting_id, a_big_integer, bar, ..etc ) " +
            "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ..etc )";

        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                FeedEntry feedEntry = feedEntries.get(i);
                int index = 1;
                ps.setString(index++, foo.id());
                ps.setObject(index++, foo.getTheBigInteger(), Types.BIGINT);
                ps.setString(index++, foo.bar())
                //etc
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return foos.size();
            }
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.math.BigDecimal` for conversion of `BigInt`.
The below code should work:

```
public List<PersonInfo> select(String id) {

    BigDecimal bigDecId = new BigDecimal(id);
    JdbcTemplate select = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    return select
        .query("SELECT * FROM PE.SUPPLIER_INPUT_DATA WHERE ID = ?",
                new Object[] { bigDecId },
                new PersonRowMapper());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I updated the driver from 9.3 to 42.2.2. Then worked fine

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```